# How to track Opens and Clicks of an email using AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, tracking, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email to a verified email account. And I want to get information about if email opened by client or clicked the link in the mail. I used this article : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-email-opens-clicks/?sc_channel=el&sc_campaign=awskcvideoytorig20&sc_medium=youtube&sc_country=global&sc_geo=global&sc_category=mult&sc_outcome=aware . After implementing the all steps I can send email using Send Test Email and after click I can get the click information. But I can get Open information. You can see the test email I sent below. [image: This is my test email]
Addition to this problem I get always a topic email after send the test email. The topic email is like below. [image]

Thanks in advance!